# how can i ise i18n in unit test from react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-i18next

I'm trying to get translations from i18n files in my unit testing, I've seen other answers but they work with just one i18n file, My problem is that, I have 2 files and the folder structure is like this,

- i18n/en/translation.json
- i18n/es/translation.json

and translation.json file is written like this
`{... "info":"information", "name":"Name", ...}`
doesn't have an export default.

and here is my test file,

```
import React from 'react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import {render} from '@testing-library/react'
import AddUsers from '../../components/AddUsers'

test('Render OK',()=>{
    
    const menuLinkUp =false

    const component =render(
            <AddUsers/>
        
    )
    component.getByText(" how can i call my i18n?")
})
```

I'm using react testing library and jest for doing this.

Comment: have you tried using the IntlProvider which you can inject your locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a section in the documentation: https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing.

I would probably mock the `react-i18next` module, as it requires the least amount of changes.

```js
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  // this mock makes sure any components using the translate HoC receive the t function as a prop
  withTranslation: () => Component => {
    Component.defaultProps = { ...Component.defaultProps, t: () => "" };
    return Component;
  },
}));
```

(If you actually want to "inject" the translations: https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing#example-test-using-this-configuration)